# Swift UISwitch not working first time

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift2, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch on my view controller and i have it so when i toggle it the text of a button changes. the first time i toggle it off and on it doesnt work, but if you try it a second time it works...is there something i am missing in my code?

```
        UISwitchOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainPageViewController.switchChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


func switchChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    let value = UISwitchOutlet.on
    if value {
        self.enterRoom.titleLabel?.text = "Enter Room"
    } else {
        self.enterRoom.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.enterRoom.titleLabel?.text = "Create"


    }
}
```

Comment: defining `let value = UISwitchOutlet.on` before `if value {` conditional makes no sense. it will never go to the else option. Delete the first line and change the second to `if mySwitch.on {`

Comment: Oh my mistake I thought I had to set the default value first

Comment: just add to viewDidLoad `UISwitchOutlet.on = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. Your value would always be on, because you were setting to the switch on state.

```
func switchChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.isOn {
        self.enterRoom.titleLabel?.text = "Enter Room"
    } else {
        self.enterRoom.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.enterRoom.titleLabel?.text = "Create"
    }
}
```